# Azure SQL server deletes

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a SQL server with 16130000 rows. I need to delete around 20%. When I do a simple:

```
delete from items where jobid=12
```

Takes forever.

I stopped the query after 11 minutes. Selecting data is pretty fast why is delete so slow? Selecting 850000 rows takes around 30 seconds.

Is it because of table locks? And can you do anything about it? I would expect delete rows should be faster because you dont transfer data on the wire?

Best R, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without telling us what reservation size you are using, it is hard to give feedback on whether X records in Y seconds is expected or not.  I can tell you about how the system works so that you can make this determination with a bit more investigation by yourself, however.  The log commit rate is limited by the reservation size you purchase.  Deletes are fundamentally limited on the ability to write out log records (and replicate them to multiple machines in case your main machine dies).  When you select records, you don't have to go over the network to N machines and you may not even need to go to the local disk if the records are preserved in memory, so selects are generally expected to be faster than inserts/updates/deletes because of the need to harden log for you.

You can read about the specific limits for different reservation sizes are here:
[DTU Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases) and [vCore Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-single-databases)

One common problem customers hit is to do individual operations in a loop (like a cursor or driven from the client).  This implies that each statement has a single row updated and thus has to harden each log record serially because the app has to wait for the statement to return before submitting the next statement.  You are not hitting that since you are running a big delete as a single statement.  That could be slow for other reasons such as:

- Locking - if you have other users doing operations on the table, it could block the progress of the delete statement.  You can potentially see this by looking at sys.dm_exec_requests to see if your statement is blocking on other locks.
- Query Plan choice.  If you have to scan a lot of rows to delete a small fraction, you could be blocked on the IO to find them.  Looking at the query plan shape will help here, as will set statistics time on (I suggest you change the query to do TOP 100 or similar to get a sense of whether you are doing lots of logical read IOs vs. actual logical writes).  This could imply that your on-disk layout is suboptimal for this problem.  The general solutions would be to either pick a better indexing strategy or to use partitioning to help you quickly drop groups of rows instead of having to delete all the rows explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @conor. Gave some insights - very helpfull. As we speak its on a Standard plan I will try to increase just of curiosity to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance) techniques to improve performance, minimize log usage and avoid consuming database space.

```
declare 
       @batch_size int,
       @del_rowcount int = 1

set @batch_size = 100
set nocount on;

while @del_rowcount > 0
       begin
              begin tran
                     delete top (@batch_size)
                     from dbo.LargeDeleteTest

                     set @del_rowcount = @@rowcount

                     print 'Delete row count: ' + cast(@del_rowcount as nvarchar(32))

              commit tran
       end
```

Drop any foreign keys, delete the rows and then recreate the foreign keys can speed up things also.

Comment: I took 31 minutes to delete 700k elements. Is that expected behaviour?